# How do I use numpy to form a 2D array from another array's columns(dimension is 2*4) given an array of indices of column number efficiently

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to make an array of 2 by n using numpy, elements inside come from specific columns selected by an array of column numbers.
For example if I have something like this

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [2, 3, 4]]
```

as my input array, and i want to have columns

`[2,3,1,2,3]`,

i will get

```
 [[2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 
  [3, 4, 2, 3, 4]]
```

as my output array

Answer (score 1):

You want to slice along the second dimension.  However, keep in mind that `numpy` uses zero based indexing.  You'll need `[1, 2, 0, 1, 2]` instead of `[2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`

```
a = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 4]])

a[:, [1, 2, 0, 1, 2]]

array([[2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 2, 3, 4]])

​
```

Comment: I've thought of using this, but it says too many indices when i run it

Comment: Likely, you have an object array of lists.  I'm guessing, but that could do it.  Try `a = np.array(a.tolist())` then slice.  If that resolves it then you want to reevaluate how you constructed your array in the first place as you may have performance bottlenecks somewhere.